# strongSwan: /var/run/charon.vici file does not exist issue

Tags: installation, vpn, ipsec

I have a Ubuntu Server 16.04 VM in VirtualBox, downloaded and installed strongSwan on it using commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make libgmp3-dev build-essential

wget http://download.strongswan.org/strongswan-5.6.0.tar.bz2
tar xjvf strongswan-5.6.0.tar.bz2
cd strongswan-5.6.0

./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
sudo make
sudo make install
```

After `sudo make` it states that vici plugin will be installed:

```
strongSwan will be built with the following plugins
-----------------------------------------------------
libstrongswan: aes des rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem fips-prf gmp curve25519 xcbc cmac hmac
libcharon:     attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke vici updown xauth-generic
libtnccs:     
libtpmtss:
```

But after building and installing `swanctl --stats` outputs:

```
connecting to 'unix:///var/run/charon.vici' failed: No such file or directory
Error: connecting to 'default' URI failed: No such file or directory
strongSwan 5.6.0 swanctl
```

Everything is done step-by-step as on [strongSwan Installation Documentation](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/InstallationDocumentation). What is the possible reason it is not working?

Comment: Did you start the daemon?

Comment: @ecdsa just did that and now everything is working! Should you answer this question below?

Comment: It is done with this command `sudo /usr/libexec/ipsec/charon &`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to problem is starting charon daemon and enabling strongswan service (so after reboot it will start automatically). For my installation I need to use these commands:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ipsec/charon &
sudo systemctl enable strongswan.service
```

Also, I added this option to configuration, since I use Ubuntu Server 16.04 with systemd:

`sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system`